# @EmbeddedKafka not working with Spring-Boot 3.2* or or Spring 6.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

We have upgraded the spring-boot version with 3.2.1. Post that embedded Kafka(@EmbeddedKafka) is not able to start.

Java version: 17.0.8
MVN version: 3.5.8

Sub Module POM

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.fault</groupId>
    <artifactId>topology</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<name>cdc-service</name>
<artifactId>cdc-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>       
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    </dependency>  -->
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.cdc.MyServiceApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Parent Module Pom

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- common -->
        <spring.boot.version>3.2.1</spring.boot.version>
        <jasypt.spring.version>3.0.5</jasypt.spring.version>
</properties>
```

It is throwing below the exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/coordinator/group/assignor/RangeAssignor
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:179) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:746) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.DeleteTopicEnableProp(KafkaConfig.scala)
```

We have added the required jar (kafka-cordinator jar) to resolve this issue. But after that, it throws some other class not found error. Is this dependency required?

Test Class level annotation

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {"auto.create.topics.enable=false"}, topics = {"topic1","topic2"}, ports = 9092)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

Does any extra thing need to be added here for the latest version?

**EDIT 2**

With kraft = false our actual problem not resolve. @EmbeddedKafka is still not working.

In the Sample05 project, we have added a new test class like below and made spring.kafka.global.embedded.enabled = false

```
  @SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {"auto.create.topics.enable=false"}, topics = {"topic1","topic2"}, ports = 9092, kraft  = false )
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestEmbeddedKF {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public void init() {
    }
    }
```

Now in the sample project throwing the below error, the same kind of error in our project we are experiencing.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable
        at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker.java:800)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker.java:298)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:130)
        at org.spr
```

In our module

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Map
at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.1-test.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaZKBroker.java:800)
```

In both cases error from the same file TestUtils.scala. Are there any solutions/defects already there for this problem?

With dynamic port option also we are getting the same exception.

Comment: That sample works if you provide a proper bootstrap server in the properties. Right now it is expecting the server via another property in the sample - `${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}`. You shouldn't have to add any extra dependencies. Looks like something else is going on here. Could you provide a standalone sample where this is happening?

Comment: There is not Testcontainers in that sample. The Kafka broker is started by the Embedded Kafka components.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have updated the question with pom details. Any comment on latest update please let me know

Comment: @sobychacko I was looking the sample project as it was not working with direct version upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The `@EmbeddedKafka` starting with Spring for Apache Kafka `3.1` uses KRaft algorithm by default. The `KafkaClusterTestKit` from Kafka Client does not support an explicit port.
Or don't use that `ports = 9092` or use `kraft = false`.

See more info in the closed issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2916

**UPDATE**

According to your latest error and what you show in the POM, you are missing these dependencies for test scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the latest error in the Edit 2 section, please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: We are getting the same scala-related error mentioned above with the above dependencies too. As sample05 project already has these dependencies we just added a new test class with @EmbeddedKafka and the result is same.

Comment: One new observation is with kafka_2.12 and other dependencies with the above version scala-related error not coming. kafka_2.13 is not able to load runtime dependencies related to scala. How we can use kafka_2.13 for embedded kafka with the latest spring boot version.?

Comment: Just to be sure. Are we talking about the same sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples/sample-05 ?

Comment: Yes we are refering the same project. We are using the same set of dependencies in our project too.

Comment: OK. But that sample works well for us. I just did `mvnw test` and it is OK on the latest `main` with Spring Boot `3.2.1`. It would be great to see what changes you did to that sample to make it fail. Perhaps you can share some project with us on GitHub to let us to reproduce and play with?